# LM2907 schematic critique

Tags: integrated-circuit, design, schematics, charge-pump, physical-design

I have been working with the [LM2907](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2907-n.pdf) as I have been designing a few circuits around it. This has lead to me wanting to understand more of its inner workings and build up a breadboard model of the internal circuit. The reason for not just using the chip is I need to display the relative key functions.

**The Ouestion**

Is there possible errors in the below schematic? Specifically:

- Charge Pump
- The use of `Q2` to charge the `22nF` which is in the external area
- My choice of `C1`, being electrolytic

*Below is the schematic referring to the question:*

[image: LM2907 internal]
**How I believe it should work:**

The comparator (IC1A) would turn the input frequency into the correct "pulse" to the Charge Pump.

The Charge pump is based off of a single stage charge pump model. I placed `Q2` so as to charge `C2` as would the LM2907 do.

After this it would go to the OP-AMP, aside LM741 is used but could be any, which will control the output resistor `Q1` with feedback to the Inverting input from the emitter.

---

*Reference Schematics*

These are images from the datasheet. The first is the circuit to which the above is meant to mimic in operation(less components for visibility).

[image]

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 2):

No, your "charge pump" circuit doesn't make any sense and won't work.

If you look at the equivalent circuit in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2907-n.pdf) (figure 51 on page 21), and then read the functional description on page 8, you'll see that it's much more complicated than that.

The charge pump monitors the output of the input comparator, and on every transition, it charges or discharges the timing capacitor `C1` between 0.25×Vcc and 0.75×Vcc using a constant-current source. While `C1` is charging or discharging, a fixed current flows out of pin 3 and through R1. This converts each input transition into a fixed-width output pulse. The resulting duty cycle is then averaged by C2 in order to turn it into an analog voltage, for which the output opamp provides buffering.

Comment: I guess it did look simple contrasted to the actual thing, do you think its possible to set something up with the second half of the comparator and a PNP, NPN pair and a current source, or is that still far off?

Comment: No, I don't think it's that simple, either. It take at least two comparators, some logic, and several current mirrors in addition to switching transistors and a current source.

Comment: No point in me trying to reinvent the wheel with squares at this point. My endeavors to make a model can wait at this point. +1 too.